# Renewing Token - where to store credentials?

Tags: token

In my app after initially logging in using `username` and `password`, the server returns a `time-based token`. This `token` needs to be sent to the `server` on each `request`.

When the `token` expires, a call must be made to the `server` to return a new `token`. This requires the `user` to pass his `username` and `password`.

My question is how should I be storing these credentials for when I need to get a new `token`?  Or should I be trying to get a new `token` just before the old one expires?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with javascript, or any code at all. It's entirely about security and the definition of your system. If you plan to keep the username / password combination in memory and use them without notifying the user, there no point in expiration of the token in the first place.

Comment: If someone were to get a hold of the token, they would be able access the system forever? The tokens I generate are not stored in my DB. They have the required info embedded in them. Sending the username/password to renew the token would occur a lot less frequently so I figured the chance of that being compromised would be less.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the token "live" for X minutes (depends on you) after the last time the user was active, means that with each request to the server the timer of the token should be reset .

once the token has expired, the user should get notice and maybe re-enter his credentials, depeneds on how secure you want your system to be, are you allowing 'remember me' option, etc ..

If you are allowing 'remember me' option, then the user should just click 'log in' and the credentials can be saved in the cookies, encrypted ( for very secure system you may use public - private key pattern ). If you are not letting the user to choose such option then he should re-enter his credentials once the token is expired .

Of course this is a suggestion and some other implementation can be done, but i think this is what are trying to do .